# Boto3 - Wait until AWS Database Migration Task is deleted

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-dms

**Requirement:** Delete DMS Task, DMS Endpoints and Replication Instance.

**Use :** Boto3 python script in Lambda

**My Approach:**
1. Delete the Database Migration Task first as Endpoint and Replication Instance cant be deleted before deleting this.
2. Delete Endpoints
3. Delete Replication Instance

**Issue:** When i am running these 3 delete commands, i get the following error

> "errorMessage": "An error occurred (InvalidResourceStateFault) when calling the DeleteEndpoint operation:Endpoint arn:aws:dms:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:endpoint:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is part of one or more ReplicationTasks.

Here i know that Data migration task will take some time to delete. So till then Endpoint will be occupied by Task. So we cant delete it.

There is a aws cli command to check whether task is deleted or not - [replication-task-deleted](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dms/wait/replication-task-deleted.html).

I can run this in shell and wait(sleep) until i get the final status and then execute delete Endpoint script.

There is no equivalent command in [Boto3 DMS docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/dms.html#DatabaseMigrationService.Client.delete_event_subscription)

Is there any other Boto3 command i can use to check the status and make my python script sleep till that time?

Please let me know if i can approach the the issue in different way.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [waiters](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/dms.html#waiters) In your case the [Waiter.ReplicationTaskDeleted](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/dms.html#DatabaseMigrationService.Waiter.ReplicationTaskDeleted)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Waiter seems to be way to go. I am able to implement waiter for EC2 and other services however i have tried to implement it for DMS Task, its not working properly for me as expected. Can you provide an implemented example? It will be very helpful.

Comment: I am not able to implement waiters.. finally implemented logic with time.sleep .. let me know if you can provide me an example for waiters.

Comment: Can you update your question with a code snippet that doesn't work as expected? Any error messages you're getting?